# jQuery DataTables PDF options not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have added the following pdf options to jQuery DataTables - the page runs; the pdf gets created; but the options (landscape and message text) don't take effect.

```
   $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "bStateSave": true,
    "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
        localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_'+window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData) );
    },
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
        return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('DataTables_'+window.location.pathname) );
    },
    "sDom": 'CT<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oColVis": {
        "buttonText": "Show/Hide",
        "aiExclude": [ 0 ],
        "bRestore": true,
        "sAlign": "left"
    },
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sButtonText": "Excel",
                "mColumns": "visible"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "sPdfMessage": "Service Request System",
                "mColumns": "visible"
            }
        ],
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the landscape option not working, but increasing the page size made it to work `"sExtends": "pdf","sPdfSize": "A3"`.